# internet connection checking is not working in android app, when i installed varies devices

Tags: java, android

My code

```
private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (cm != null)
        {
            NetworkInfo[] info = cm.getAllNetworkInfo();
            if (info != null)
                for (int i = 0; i < info.length; i++)
                    if (info[i].getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
                    {
                        return true;
                    }

        }
        connectionceck();
        return false;

    }

    private void connectionceck()
    {
        final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder= new AlertDialog.Builder(HomeActivity.this);
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Internet NOT availablle, ");
        alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Turn on the Internet to use App Efficiently");
        alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false);
        alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

            }
        });
        alertDialogBuilder.setNeutralButton("Try Again", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                if (isNetworkAvailable());

            }
        });
        alertDialogBuilder.show();

    }
```

Comment: did you add this permission in manifest file `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />`

Comment: ya i have added

Comment: Which devices you add?

Comment: samsung android version  5.0.1

Answer (score 0):

try this create a simple class like this

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;

import com.ncrypted.connectin.R;

public class ConnectionCheck {

    public boolean isNetworkConnected(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo ni = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (ni == null) {
            // There are no active networks.
            return false;
        } else
            return true;
    }

    public AlertDialog.Builder showconnectiondialog(Context context) {

        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                .setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setTitle("Error!")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setMessage("No Internet Connection.")
                .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    }
                });

        return builder;
    }
}
```

when you need to check INTERNET is available or not than check it like this

```
ConnectionCheck connectionCheck= new ConnectionCheck();
 if (connectionCheck.isNetworkConnected(HomeClass.this)) {
                    // internet is avialable
     Toast.makeText(this, "Intenet Is Avialable", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  } else {
       connectionCheck.showconnectiondialog(HomeClass.this).show();

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code :

```
 public static boolean haveNetworkConnection(Context context) {
        boolean haveConnectedWifi = false;
        boolean haveConnectedMobile = false;

        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo[] netInfo = cm.getAllNetworkInfo();
        for (NetworkInfo ni : netInfo) {
            if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("WIFI"))
                if (ni.isConnected())
                    haveConnectedWifi = true;
            if (ni.getTypeName().equalsIgnoreCase("MOBILE"))
                if (ni.isConnected())
                    haveConnectedMobile = true;
        }
        return haveConnectedWifi || haveConnectedMobile;
    }
```

and also add these permission in `manifest.xml`

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to do it:

First, create a static method like below

```
/**
* Checks the device is online or not
*/
public static boolean isOnline(Context mContext) {
    if (mContext != null) {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) mContext.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Second, add your permission to your manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Usage:

```
if (!isOnline(mContext)) {
    //Not connected, Do your action
}
```